# How to set autocommit to false in pyspark jdbc when overwriting the data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, databricks, azure-databricks

I wanted to check if spark jdbc provides a way to set the autocommit to false. I am writing the dataframe to a postgres table which already has some data. If there are any write issues, the complete table is getting dropped and the previous data is lost. Even if I use truncate=True option in the jdbc properties, the table structure remains but the data is lost. So is there a way to set autocommit to false and manually commit after the write is successful?

I am using the following jdbc connection string.

```
targeturl = f"jdbc:postgresql://{host_tar}:{port_tar}/{db_tar}?currentSchema={schema_tar}"
```

Do we have any additional parameters to add to this URL for setting off the autocommit?

Answer (score 0):

To set the autoCommit property to false in the JDBC connection URL, you can modify the targeturl

```
targeturl = f"jdbc:postgresql://{host_tar}:{port_tar}/{db_tar}?currentSchema={schema_tar}&autoCommit=false"
```

[image]

This will set the autoCommit property to false in the JDBC connection URL, which will disable autocommit and allow you to manually commit the transaction after the write is successful.

you can manually commit the transaction by calling the commit method on the JDBC connection object.

```
df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", targeturl) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

You Can commit the transaction Manually like this

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(targeturl, username, password)
connection.commit()
```